What is the indefinite article used in "like a jean"?
There is a scene in the movie "Ocean's Eleven" in which one of the characters is talking to an owner of a car dealership. When he introduces himself as Denham this dialogue takes place:
Frank: Denham like a jean?
Car dealership owner: That's it. Just like the jean."
QUESTION 1: Why Frank uses the indefinite article before "jean"? It's a fabric which should be uncountable and when used in the sense of "a pair of pants made out of this material" it's always in the plural AFAIK.
QUESTION 2: When the card dealership owner says "the jean" does he refer to the fabric that a pair of jeans is made out of? If not, what?
noun: jean
heavy twilled cotton cloth, especially denim.
"a jean jacket"(Oxford Languages)

Where does the car dealer say "the denim"?

https://www.dpvintageposters.com/posters/horizontal-posters/levi-s-a-jean-for-all-seasons-original-advertising-poster_204

@TimR He doesn't. I made a mistake. Post is edited.

I think you meant to ask Why is an article used? and not "What is the indefinite article…?" because the answer would be "a" . Why DOES Frank use... -1


We often use a definite article when asking to confirm our understanding of something someone has referred to, e.g. Person A: My name is Joe Lion. Person B: Like the big cat in Africa? Person A: That's right.

If the actual film departs from the published script, and the car dealer does say 'the denim' then he is talking about the denim material used in the manufacture of jeans.


Using 'jean' (singular) to talk about the well-known denim trousers is something often done by people in the fashion or clothing industries.

Denim Rises Explained: When brands describe the rise of a jean, they're simply referring to the distance (usually in inches) from the
centre crotch seam, to the top of the waist band.
If you are buying a jean constructed from Photo Ready Denim (J Brand's slimming, lifting and contouring denim with shape recovery...
The 25 best denim brands to shop now, according to a jean addict

Also, the word 'jean' (without an 's' at the end) can be used to refer to the denim material itself, (i.e. 'jean' or 'jean cloth') and is typically used as a modifier to describe garments that are made of this material, as in 'jean jacket or jean shorts'.


The main point of course is that Frank is asking the question to confirm that he's heard the name correctly:

"Hi, I'm Mr Denham.
"Do you mean Denham like the denim material they use to make jeans?"
"Exactly."

When spoken, Denham and denim sound the same.
As to the grammar of the conversation, this is entirely reasonable. Native speakers often use short comparative sentences using like a or as a.

cool like a cucumber.
big as a house.
fast like a race horse.

We should understand it as scripted dialogue intended to be informal and fast paced. If I was writing precise literary sentences I might expand the conversation as I did in the example above. But that wouldn't be a style of speaking consistent with the character. All Frank is doing is using a standard comparative structure and inserting into it the word jean. That's all he needs. The indefinite article is used because the jean is non specific, like the other example comparisons above.

Denham and denim don't sound the same to me.

Regional differences? I get that, but in the context of the movie, surely we need to interpret them as homophones to make sense of the exchange.

In AmE they sound the same most places. Here's the scene. The subtitles are full of errors,beware.  https://youtu.be/9Kcv4a_DQD0
